# Mysql with <User input> cant create table

Tags: python, mysql

Pythonista.

I am doing a Mysql database that first ask the user for the data base name. that works.
Once database is created it doest create the tables put prints out this error:

*if not self._connection:
ReferenceError: weakly-referenced object no longer exists*

Here is the code:
'''

```
import mysql.connector
 
 
# Create database
database_name = input(">> ")
db = mysql.connector.connect(
    host='localhost',
    user='root',
    passwd='Mysql2021',)
 
my_cursor = db.cursor()
my_cursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS %s" %database_name)
 
db = mysql.connector.connect(
    host='localhost',
    user='root',
    passwd='Mysql2021',
    database=database_name)
 
# Create table
my_cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE test1 (firstname VARCHAR(255),lastname VARCHAR(255)")
```

'''
thank you for your help.

Comment: Recreate the cursor after changing `db`? `my_cursor = db.cursor()`

Comment: By doing so i get an syntax error of sql. <mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1>

Comment: Missing a closing parenthesis `)` after your field names I think

Comment: yes i just saw that, thank you i didn t get any error, i added the new cursor() and added the missing )

Comment: It worked thank @lainShelvington

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing an opening bracket on the database name. It should ideally be like this:

```
my_cursor = db.cursor()
my_cursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS %s" %(database_name)
```

With the full code looking like this:

```
import mysql.connector
 
 
# Create database
database_name = input(">> ")
db = mysql.connector.connect(
    host='localhost',
    user='root',
    passwd='Mysql2021',)
 
my_cursor = db.cursor()
my_cursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS %s" %(database_name)
 
db = mysql.connector.connect
    host='localhost',
    user='root',
    passwd='Mysql2021',
    database=database_name)
 
# Create table
my_cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE test1 (firstname VARCHAR(255),lastname VARCHAR(255)")
```